# MKStoreKit Errors

Tags: xcode

I go this error with MKStoreKit 5.
I added -objc-arc flag on all MKStoreKit files but I got this error.

```
Ld /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar-fpyxztssnpchdoalmoynsjjmsekg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NanoWar.app/NanoWar normal i386
    cd /Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar-fpyxztssnpchdoalmoynsjjmsekg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone/NanoWar2/libs/TestFlightSDK1.0 -L/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone/../../iOS/Chartboost -L/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone/NanoWar2/libs/Chartboost -F/Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar-fpyxztssnpchdoalmoynsjjmsekg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Benoit/Workshop/Dropbox/NanoWar2_Iphone -filelist /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar-fpyxztssnpchdoalmoynsjjmsekg/Build/Intermediates/NanoWar.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NanoWar.build/Objects-normal/i386/NanoWar.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lz -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -framework StoreKit -weak_framework Social -weak_framework Twitter -weak_framework AdSupport -weak-lSystem -lz -framework GameKit -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenGLES -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lTestFlight -lChartboost -o /Users/Benoit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NanoWar-fpyxztssnpchdoalmoynsjjmsekg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NanoWar.app/NanoWar

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecItemUpdate", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_SecKeyRawVerify", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustCopyInfo", referenced from:
      -[VerificationController validateTrust:error:] in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
      -[VerificationController validateTrust:error:] in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_SecTrustSetVerifyDate", referenced from:
      _checkReceiptSecurity in VerificationController.o
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecAttrLabel", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
  "_kSecTrustInfoExtendedValidationKey", referenced from:
      -[VerificationController validateTrust:error:] in VerificationController.o
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to link your project with `Security.framework` - go to your target settings / Build phases and add it to the "Link Binary with Libraries" list:

[image]